# Firebase Firestore not reciving enters/ returns in the database, with material ui and react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My code is perfectly working but when I type into the "material UI text field" And try to set a document in Firestone, it does not include any returns. The entire document is one big string without any separation.

This makes it really difficult to use in the database.

it would also be useful to know how to place 'enters' in the firebase database through the firebase comsole*

The relevant bits of the code

Text field

```
  import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

<form onSubmit={this.submit}>
    <TextField  
      className={Style.TextField}
      multiline
      rows="9"
      size="small" variant="filled" 
value= {this.state.Bio}
onChange= {this.BioChange}/>
```

The function for form submission.

```
submit = event => 
{
     event.preventDefault();         

   let  db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("Bio").doc(`${firebase.auth().currentUser.email}`).set({  
    Bio: `${this.state.Bio}`,
   });
}
```

for example, if I type into the text field and submit

"How many lines can I submit?

maybe 1

maybe 3 "

it will come out as:

""How mnay lines cna i submit? maybe 1 maybe 3 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using regular expressions. 
First, replace line breaks with '\n' in your `textarea` value.

```
inputValue.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
```

now send this new value to firestore.
To display the value again reverse the procedure.

```
receivedValue.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```

[example](https://codepen.io/4hmaad/pen/dyYmamo)

Comment: I mean when I type into the input on the website. Not when i type into the HTML to be displayed.

Or where do I put the n/  if it's meant for the text field?

Comment: you can store this /n on the field for the returns and when it is displayed use what @Ahmed said

Comment: @AlexanderHemming check the updated answer, I hope it will help.

Comment: the reverse doesn't seem to work. <><><>

   this.setState({
              Bio: docSnapshot.data(),
              body: this.state.Bio.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
          });

and 

<h4>{this.state.Bio.Bio} 
            {this.state.body.Bio}
</h4>
<><><>
makes only the this.state.body.Bio} appear. The other is non-existant.

Comment: I managed to do what you suggested, and it replaces the /n with the return key supplement, but this still leads to a lack of new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer. 
If you have something with "return keys" even in your state you would need to add

```
<div style = {{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}
```

this template literal is needed for you to have the return keys in your HTML. Otherwise, they will automatically be replaced with spaces.